# elasticsearch phrase_prefix expected results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I'm having some weird behavior with elastic search.
I'm using custom analyzer with custom tokenizer which spilts the words in case of
space, + , -.

when I'm searching

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "name.default": {
        "query": "paris oly"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get results as expected
paris olympia etc...
but when I'm searching

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "name.default": {
        "query": "paris ol"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get no results at all.

settings:

```
     "analysis": {
           "analyzer": {
              "customAnalyzer": {
                 "type": "custom",
                 "filter": "lowercase",
                 "tokenizer": "customTokenizer"
              },
           "tokenizer": {
              "customTokenizer": {
                 "pattern": "[\\+\\s-]",
                 "type": "pattern"
              }
           }
        }
```

field mapping:

```
{
    "name": {
              "properties": {
                        "default": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "customAnalyzer"
                 }
            }
        }
}
```

sample of part of the doc (the requested field):

```
 { 
"name": {
              "jp": "パリ オリンピア (劇場)",
              "default": "Paris Olympia",
              }
}

{    
    "TYPE_NAME": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "name": {
            "path_match": "*name.*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "customAnalyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "point": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your mapping, including the analyzer, and a few sample docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried testing what you posted, it worked for me. I'll post what I did and you can look at it and see if you can figure out what's different about your setup, and if you have further questions I'll try to help.

I created an index using the mapping and analyzer/tokenizer you posted, then added the doc you posted:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "analysis": {
         "tokenizer": {
            "customTokenizer": {
               "pattern": "[\\+\\s-]",
               "type": "pattern"
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "customAnalyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "filter": "lowercase",
               "tokenizer": "customTokenizer"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "properties": {
                  "default": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "customAnalyzer"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "name": {
      "jp": "パリ オリンピア (劇場)",
      "default": "Paris Olympia"
   }
}
```

Then either of the queries you posted returned the document for me:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match_phrase_prefix": {
         "name.default": {
            "query": "paris oly"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.38356602,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.38356602,
            "_source": {
               "name": {
                  "jp": "パリ オリンピア (劇場)",
                  "default": "Paris Olympia"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

or

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match_phrase_prefix": {
         "name.default": {
            "query": "paris ol "
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.38356602,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.38356602,
            "_source": {
               "name": {
                  "jp": "パリ オリンピア (劇場)",
                  "default": "Paris Olympia"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used, for convenience:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4e58344580dcf01299f7cc2199d0fb7694d2a051

So there must be something else going on. Can you tell what is different about your setup from what I tried?

*Edit:* I did have to switch the order of the tokenizer and analyzer, because I got an error otherwise. So you might want to look into that.

Comment: Thanks again!
well I switched the order as you said. and now the case from my exmple is working!!.
but I still have issue when I'm searching "paris o".
the difference between us is 
1.I'm using java client to insert
2.since I'm using objects in my docs I'm using "dynamic_templates" in my settings (added to the main post)